# HTTP Credentials are not added to GET request

Tags: android, http, get

I have the next code to set the configuration of basic authentication of a page where i have to take data from android app. The problem is that i can not get data because connectionState is 401 ("No authorized"). That is more, the Http authorization header is correct, the same that the generated by the browser but WITHOUT CREDENTIALS.

```
public static void  setHttpBasicAuth(String user, String passwd){
    String basicAuth = Base64.encodeToString(String.format("%s:%s",user,passwd).getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
    properties.put(AUTH, String.format("Basic %s", basicAuth));
}
```

I do not understand why the credentials are not being added like "user:passwd"